# Guess that number, Larger or Smaller?

Tags: c#, number-guessing-game

I created a simple guessing game for the sake of practice, it's been a while since I've had any code reviewed. I do have a tendency to over-engineer things sometimes and I'm not typically aware of it until well after the programs creation, so please let me know if I've done such a thing. Other than that, I'm open to any and all suggestions.

Note, I did use mathematical notation of [1, 101) to denote that 1 is in the valid range of numbers and 101 in not included in the valid range of numbers.

**Program.cs**

```
public class Program
{
    private const string IntroductionStatement = "Guess the randomly chosen number.\r\nYou will be told if the number is LARGER or SMALLER than your guess after each attempt.";
    private const string VictoryStatement = "You have won the game!";
    private const string DefeatStatement = "Sorry, you have lost the game!";
    private const string IncorrectGuessStatement = "Sorry that was incorrect.";
    private const string PromptStatement = "How many attempts would you like? ";
    private const string GuessStatement = "Your Guess: ";

    private const string NumberRangeStatement = "The possible range of numbers is [{0}, {1}).\r\n";
    private const string CurrentAttemptStatement = "\r\nAttempt #{0} of {1}.";
    private const string LargerSmallerStatment = "The number is {0} than your guess.";
    private const string AnswerStatement = "The number was {0}.";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(IntroductionStatement);
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format(NumberRangeStatement, GuessThatNumberGame.MinimumNumber, GuessThatNumberGame.MaximumNumber));

        int maxAttempts = GetMaxAttemptsFromPlayer();
        var game = new GuessThatNumberGame(maxAttempts);

        do
        {

            Console.WriteLine(String.Format(CurrentAttemptStatement, game.Attempt, game.MaxAttempts));
            var playerGuess = GetNumberGuessFromPlayer();
            game.SubmitGuess(playerGuess);

            if (game.HasBeenWon != true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(IncorrectGuessStatement + " " + String.Format(LargerSmallerStatment, game.Number > playerGuess ? "LARGER" : "SMALLER"));
            }

        } while (game.HasBeenWon == null); // True means we've won, False means we've lost. Null means it's still in progress.

        Console.WriteLine($"\r\n{(game.HasBeenWon == true ? VictoryStatement : DefeatStatement)}");
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format(AnswerStatement, game.Number));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static int GetMaxAttemptsFromPlayer()
    {
        return GetNumberFromPlayer(PromptStatement);
    }

    private static int GetNumberGuessFromPlayer()
    {
        return GetNumberFromPlayer(GuessStatement);
    }

    private static int GetNumberFromPlayer(string prompt)
    {
        var number = 0;
        do
        {
            Console.Write(prompt);
        } while (Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number) == false);
        return number;
    }
}
```

**GuessThatNumberGame.cs**

```
public class GuessThatNumberGame
{
    private static Random _Randomizer = new Random();

    public const int MinimumNumber = 1;
    public const int MaximumNumber = 101;

    public int Attempt { get; private set; }
    public int MaxAttempts { get; private set; }
    public int Number { get; private set; }
    public bool? HasBeenWon { get; private set; }

    public GuessThatNumberGame(int maxAttempts)
    {
        if (maxAttempts <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("maxAttempts");
        }

        Number = _Randomizer.Next(MinimumNumber, MaximumNumber);
        MaxAttempts = maxAttempts;
        Attempt = 1;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Enter a guess from the player.
    /// </summary>
    public void SubmitGuess(int guessedNumber)
    {
        // No more attempts if they've already lost.
        if (HasBeenWon == false)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Add this to the number of attempts.
        Attempt += 1;

        // If they guessed correctly set to victory.
        if (guessedNumber == Number)
        {
            HasBeenWon = true;
        }

        // This was their last attempt if we're over the max now.
        if (Attempt > MaxAttempts)
        {
            HasBeenWon = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Sample: Victory**

> Guess the randomly chosen number. You will be told if the number is
>   LARGER or SMALLER than your guess after each attempt. The possible
>   range of numbers is [1, 101).
>
> How many attempts would you like? 10
>
> Attempt #1 of 10. Your Guess: 50
>   Sorry that was incorrect. The number is SMALLER than your guess.
>
> Attempt #2 of 10. Your Guess: 25
>   Sorry that was incorrect. The number is LARGER than your guess.
>
> Attempt #3 of 10. Your Guess: 35
>   Sorry that was incorrect. The number is LARGER than your guess.
>
> Attempt #4 of 10. Your Guess: 40
>   Sorry that was incorrect. The number is LARGER than your guess.
>
> Attempt #5 of 10. Your Guess: 45
>   Sorry that was incorrect. The number is SMALLER than your guess.
>
> Attempt #6 of 10. Your Guess: 43 
>   Sorry that was incorrect. The number is LARGER than your guess.
>
> Attempt #7 of 10. Your Guess: 44
>
> You have won the game! The number was 44.

**Sample: Defeat**

> Guess the randomly chosen number. You will be told if the number is
>   LARGER or SMALLER than your guess after each attempt. The possible
>   range of numbers is [1, 101).
>
> How many attempts would you like? 5
>
> Attempt #1 of 5. Your Guess: 50
>   Sorry that was incorrect. The number is SMALLER than your guess.
>
> Attempt #2 of 5. Your Guess: 25
>   Sorry that was incorrect. The number is SMALLER than your guess.
>
> Attempt #3 of 5. Your Guess: 12
>   Sorry that was incorrect. The number is SMALLER than your guess.
>
> Attempt #4 of 5. Your Guess: 6
>   Sorry that was incorrect. The number is SMALLER than your guess.
>
> Attempt #5 of 5. Your Guess: 3
>   Sorry that was incorrect. The number is LARGER than your guess.
>
> Sorry, you have lost the game! The number was 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Magic Values

I took a look on your source code. It is quite good, and I like the way you define constants for values, but there are still some magic values, such as **"maxAttempts"**.

### Exceptions

In side the method **GuessThatNumberGame(int maxAttempts)**, you throw an **ArgumentOutOfRangeException**. I think you can add more detail in the error message then it is easier to understand the problem exactly. Maybe:

```
throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("maxAttempts must be more than 0");
```

And I don't see where do you handle the exception. As an user, I expected that I will receive some error message when I enter an invalid value instead of the app crash.

### UX:

Let see this function:

> ```
> private static int GetNumberFromPlayer(string prompt)
>         {
>             var number = 0;
>             do
>             {
>                 Console.Write(prompt);
>             } while (Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number) == false);
>             return number;
>         }
> ```

It look good, but when user input invalid numbers( ex: a string) then nothing show to the console, user can not understand what is their next step. I think you can check the input there, and ask user enter a number:

```
private static int GetNumberFromPlayer(string prompt)
{
    var number = 0;
    Console.Write(prompt);

    do
    {           
        If(Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number))
        {
            break;  
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("please enter a number");   
        }
    } while (true);
    return number;
}
```

Regard!

Comment: Could you elaborate on the first point please? Not sure how `maxAttempts` is a magic value since it's obtained from the user. Unless you're referring to my exception if-statement preventing it from being less than 1?

Comment: Hi, I mean the string "maxAttempts", not the int maxAttempts.
P/S: when you are using condition, don't need to compare with value.( while (Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number), instead of while (Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number) == false) ).

Comment: Did you mean `while(!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number)`? because `while(Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number)` is the opposite condition I wish to check. If that is what you meant, I prefer `== false` to `!` because it's easier to notice while scrolling through the code.

Comment: I had just `"maxAttempts"` because the first parameter for the first overload of `ArgumentOutOfRangeException(..)` was named `paramName` but I suppose it does have another overload where the parameter's name is `message` so thanks for that. Thanks for the UX section too, in this case I think I would keep it the way it is (they should know they're playing a *number* guessing game) but I do fail to consider other user possibilities quite often so it's great advice!

Comment: I'm not sure why this hasn't been mentioned, but there's a `nameof` operator that allows you to replace `"maxAttempts"` with `nameof(maxAttempts)`, making it refactor-proof.

Comment: HI Pieter, I agree with you about that. Because I think I proposed to change the error message to throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("maxAttempts must be more than 0") then I did not mention about that.